# Removing sublists where index is duplicated

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I'm trying to sort through a nested list and remove sublists based on its [0][0][0] index. I can get it to work if the rest of the list is also identical, however, with the first index ([0][0][0]) the same and the rest of the sublist ([0][0][1] for instance) is different to the constant, it no longer deletes. (the code makes more sense than I do...). I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't quite find it.

```
c = [[
  ['1100', ['1100', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']],
  ['1101', ['1200', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']],
  ['1200', ['1160', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']],
  ['1201', ['1110', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']],
  ['1211', ['1230', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']],
  ['1100', ['4200', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']],
  ['1200', ['1100', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']],
  ['1235', ['1500', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']]
]]

list_len = len(c[0])
j = 0
for i in c[0]:
  list_len = len(c[0])
  occur = c[0].count(c[0][j][0])
  if occur > 1:
    c[0].reverse()
    c[0].remove(i)
    c[0].reverse()
  else:
    pass

  if j < list_len:
    j = j + 1
  else:
    pass

for x in c[0]:
  print(x)
```

**EDIT**
To clarify, the output should be:

```
['1100', ['1100', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']]
['1101', ['1200', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']]
['1200', ['1160', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']]
['1201', ['1110', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']]
['1211', ['1230', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']]
['1235', ['1500', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']]
```

So the folowing have been remove

```
['1100', ['4200', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']]
['1200', ['1100', 'other text', 'a', '1', '2']]
```

because they are the second occurance of 1100 and 1200 in the first index respectively.

Comment: can you explain what is your expected output ?

Comment: is this homework or you just need it done? do you need to implement the logic in specific way?

Answer (score 0):

on this line

```
occur = c[0].count(c[0][j][0])
```

im sure you meant to count the number of matches like this:

```
occur = c[0][j].count(c[0][j][0])
```

Also:

```
if occur > 1:
```

would not pick up when there's only one match, instead, do this:

```
if occur >= 1:
```

the code works after these tweaks. I recommend using a debugger when you code! it is pretty easy to spot the problem with one.

on a side note, you used:

```
  else:
    pass
```

I'm not sure why you did it. If you want the loop to skip the rest of the code and move to the next item in the list, you should use `continue`, `pass` is just a placeholder so the interpreter doesn't freak out.

Hope it helps! :)